# How to show google maps based on user direction

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using `Google Maps` in order to display current user location. While using the north part is always on the top, but my question is: it possible to change it based on user direction? For example, if the user turns to south, the south part should be in top.
How can i do this?

My application minimun sdk version is 2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can handle sensor events (which can give you user's bearing) and then you'll have to rotate your MapView with an animation.

You can use location.getBearing(); in order to have the user's bearing. 
then, you can rotate the view

```
// Create an animation instance 
Animation an = new RotateAnimation(from, to, pivotX, pivotY); 
// Set the animation's parameters 
an.setDuration(duration); 
an.setFillAfter(true); 
// Aply animation to view 
mapView.setAnimation(an);
```

Comment: how can i do this can u give any example

Comment: You can use location.getBearing(); in order to have the user's bearing. Then, you can rotate the view
    '// Create an animation instance
    Animation an = new RotateAnimation(from, to, pivotX, pivotY);

    // Set the animation's parameters
    an.setDuration(duration);            
    an.setFillAfter(true);              

    // Aply animation to image view
    mapView.setAnimation(an);'

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using `mapView.setRotation(bearing)`.  That's what I use (I have an app similar to yours).  I'm not sure what API level that was introduced in, but it works for me (2.3.4).  Make sure you call `mapView.invalidate()` after you've rotated the map.